# MonoGame on Xamarin Studio - Issue with Xna?

Tags: c#, android, xna, monogame, xamarin-studio

I want to give a try to MonoGame with Android Studio. I'm actually on a Mac.
I'm doing the following tutorial :

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/monogame/introduction/part1/

But just after creating the shared project, I had a screen full of missing directives / unnecessary directives like :

"Using directive is unnecessary"
"the type or namespace name 'XXXXX' could not be found"

I tried to add the "MonoGame.Framework.Android" package to the android part of the project but it did not changed a single thing.

I tried some researches but I have some difficulties to describe my problem, because I don't really understand it. I'm not sure, but I think it's coming from references.

- Did you experienced the same issue ?
- I think I miss some references (especially Xna), how do I add them on Xamarin Studio ?
- Is the Monogame Add-In deprecated ?

Comment: Can you post the exact error messages you get? Is it complaining about the namespace XNA not being found?

Comment: yeah here is the error i get when i try to build : Error: /Users/ironova/Projects/MonoGameApp/Android/MonoGameApp.Droid.csproj: /Users/ironova/Projects/MonoGameApp/Android/MonoGameApp.Droid.csproj could not import "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets" (MonoGameApp.Droid)                                And I currently miss many namespaces such as "game" and "AndroidGameActivity".

Comment: I confirm that Xna namespace is not found in autocompletion. I think that it cames from references; i'm actually trying this --> http://blog.jamie.ly/software/2013/04/23/setting-up-a-monogame-mac-application-with-xamarin-studio.html  There is no XamarinStudio-4,0 in my application support.

Comment: What if you try to download the latest stable version of the MonoGame Addin for Xamarin Studio (Links are for MonoDevelop but it shouldn't matter since Xamarin Studio is a fork of MonoDevelop). http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/47

Comment: I tried with the last stable version -3.6.0.586 (Stable). The issue seems to be the same. I'm going to try with older versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access my Mac right now so I'm not able to try to reproduce your problem. I've worked with MonoGame a lot before and know there can be all sorts of problems that are hard to solve.

Comment: thanks for your assistance anyway, I will post the answer when the issue will be resolved. I think it's just a dumb missing reference, a link problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it's done!

It was a linking problem : i did not have the needed references, I needed to install Mono and MonoGame, not just MonoGame AddIn.

Here is my solution:

1 - Uninstall the MonoGame AddIn

2- Uninstall Xamarin (yeah it's extreme)

3 - Install Mono 
http://www.mono-project.com/

4 - Install MonoGame
http://www.monogame.net/downloads/

5 - Re-Install Xamarin

6 - Activate MonoGame AddIn -> it's already there

7 - Create a SharedProject, then modify the "OnCreate" method in the Android part :

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)

{

```
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        var g = new Game1();
        SetContentView((View)g.Services.GetService(typeof(View)));
        g.Run();
```

}

8 - Profit, enjoy your MonoGameSample.

thanks to @hankide for giving his help.

This link helped me a lot:

http:// blog.jamie.ly/software/2013/04/23/setting-up-a-monogame-mac-application-with-xamarin-studio.html

PS : i don't have enought reputation to post more than 2 links so the last one have a space between "http://" and "blog.jamie"